# jquery mobile get data on click from listview and sqlite data in cordova android

Tags: android, sqlite, cordova, jquery-mobile, phonegap-plugins

I get a listview from sqlite query, but I need you to get a data on click, my example works with json, but with sqlite data it doesn't work. I don't know what is wrong.

Thank you so much.

```
function populateDB(tx) {
 tx.executeSql('SELECT Name, Latitude,Longitude FROM data', [], querySuccess, errorCB); 
}

function querySuccess(tx,result){
        $('#List').empty();
        $.each(result.rows,function(index){
        var row = result.rows.item(index);

//external CALCULATION        
var rumbo = (degrees(Math.atan2(dLong, dPhi)) + 360.0) % 360.0; 
var rumbo0 = rumbo.toFixed(0);


$('#List').append('<li><a href="#"><h3 class="ui-li-heading"> '+row['Name']+' </h3><p class="ui-li-desc">Rumbo: '+rumbo0+'  Latitude  '+Latitude+' Longitude: '+Longitude+'  </p></a></li>');
                    });

        $('#List').listview();    
                $('#List li').click(function() {
                   currentItem = $(this).index();
                   var Name = result.rows[currentItem].Name;
                   alert(Name); 
                   var bearing = result.rows[currentItem].rumbo0;
                   alert(bearing); 


});

}
```

Comment: try to print currentItem value... check whether you are getting the value or not

Comment: Thank you when printed a value show the position 0,1,..